# Is the number of protons in the mitochondrion sufficient for ATP synthesis?

Tags: mitochondria

If the proton concentration in the mitochondrial matrix (based on its pH) is multiplied by its volume, the total number of protons in somewhere in between 2 and 8.

> My question is whether this is sufficient for ATP synthesis, if 2–3
>   hydrogen ions are required for each molecule of ATP synthesized.

*My calculation is as follows:*

pH = –log[H<sup>+</sup>]

The pH of the mitochondrial matrix is ca. 8. Thus, [H<sup>+</sup>] = 10<sup>-8</sup> M (moles per litre).

If the [mitochondrial volume is 0.2 μm<sup>3</sup>](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/search.aspx) this is equivalent to 2x10<sup>-10</sup> μl = 2x10<sup>-16</sup> litre

Using Avagadro’s number as 6x10<sup>23</sup> it follows that:

Total number of protons in the matrix of a mitochondrion = 10<sup>-8</sup> x 2x10<sup>-16</sup> x 6x10<sup>23</sup>

= 1.2 (although other figures may give a value as high as 8).

If a pH of 6.8 is considered for the inter-membrane space along with a 0.1 fl volume, the number is 6.7 protons.

I found a paper where the question is adressed. First, the definition of pH at very low volumes is challenged, along with its measuring techniques. Second, it proposes novel mechanisms for proton availability in such situations. 
(http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0045832)

Comment: Can you please explain how you got to the numbers 2 and 8? For the moment, the question is unclear as we have no idea what calculation you've made and what you misunderstanding is. Also, the number of protons in a piece of matter is not the same thing as the number of free protons.

Comment: The calculation is as follows: pH=-log [H+], in mitochondrial matrix around 8. Thus,  [H+] =10(-8) M. If a mitochondrial volume of 0.2 um3 is considered (as it has been reported), Then: 10(-8) M*2.1x10(-16)L*6.022x10(23), gives a total of 1.26 H+, for example. Similar numbers can be obtained when other reported mitochondrial matrix volumes are used in the calculation.

Comment: You should edit your post to include that calculation. While you're at it, try rewording it so that it's a clear question, instead of just a statement. It's an interesting point, though

Comment: This is a chemistry question. Not really a biology question. I think [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for your question.

Comment: @Remi.b I'm guessing the chemists would say it's a biology question, since it's about mitochondria. But, again, it needs to be a question before we can say for sure what it's about :)

Comment: I don´t know how to edit the post. The question would be: how is it possible that  the stoichiometry for ATP synthesis is 2-3 H+:ATP, when there are around 2-8 total H+ in the mitochondrial matrix?

Comment: There is an edit link at the bottom of the post. If you edit it with that info, I think it will be a good, answerable question. If nobody else answers it by the time I get home, I'll answer it.

Comment: @Mithoron, If you refer to the conversion between um3 and L, I believe that 1 um3 is 1x10(-15) L (dm3), 1x10(-12) ml (cm3), and 1x10(-9) ul (mm3)

Comment: OK, then it's at least not a matter of miscalculation, but still it's just about water and pH, so still general chemistry. More to the point, you could easily pick a small enough part of any highly diluted solution, where there would be no H3O+ at all, but statistically there would be probability of finding of H3O+ in a different moment directly related to pH. As far as your synthesis goes, there are a lot of more or less acidic protons in there, just waiting to be used.

Comment: I find "a lot" hard to calculate or discuss. Could you help me? Have you got any idea of how can I calculate such probability? I´m sorry if the question didn´t match the forum spectations. Still, I think that mitochondrial function IS a biological question, even though in this case involves some chemestry bases.

Comment: I have edited the question so that it is clearer. It should also make the unexpressed assumptions — addressed in my answer — more obvious. If I have changed your meaning, do say so, but try to keep things clear.

Comment: @David, thanks a lot. I added the numbers for inter-membrane calculation, and the reference to the paper I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The question, as amended, can be summarized as:

> If there are 2–8 protons in the mitochondrial matrix (as calculated
>   from a pH of 8) is this sufficient for ATP synthesis, if 2–3 hydrogen
>   ions are required for each molecule of ATP synthesized?

The initial deficiency in the argument was that it did not consider the inter-membrane space, and my answer was:

- According to the generally accepted [Mitchell Hypothesis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22388/), the generation of ATP in the
  mitochondrion is due to an electrochemical gradient between the
  mitochondrial matrix and the inter-membrane space.
- This gradient is predominantly a pH gradient — the [H<sup>+</sup>] is
  higher in the inter-membrane space than in the matrix
- The flow of protons down this gradient is responsible for the
  production of ATP.
- The H<sup>+</sup> gradient is maintained by protons being pumped across the inner mitochondrial membrane by the flow of electrons through the electron transport chain. (i.e. The H<sup>+</sup> concentration is kept low in the matrix and high in the inter-membrane space, even though protons are continually flowing into the matrix.

i.e. For ATP synthesis to occur there is ***no*** requirement for a high *steady-state* concentration of hydrogen ions ***in the mitochondrial matrix*** — quite the opposite (as is reflected by the pH 8). A relatively high concentration of hydrogen ions is only required in the ***inter-membrane space*** — as is indeed found.

**The amended question** assumes a pH of 6.8 for the inter-membrane space, and calculates 8.9 protons to be in this compartment.

The poster still does not state specifically what the problem is — there is still a concentration gradient of hydrogen ions, and a vast body of experimental evidence shows that it is this gradient of hydrogen ions that drives ATP synthesis.

So the implied question does not seem specific to ATP generation, but to the concept of pH in cellular compartments of small volume. There is obviously something wrong here, and the paper quoted — which addresses this question — suggests some possible explanations:

- That the pH measured is incorrect because of the methodology
- That the hydrogen ions are not free but associated with negatively charged species (possibly phosphate ions) from which they may be released, as required.

The latter point had occurred to me before reading the paper. In summary:

- The steady-state hydrogen ion concentration gradient is sufficient to drive ATP synthesis, with many hydrogen ions at any time passing through the membrane in one direction or another.
- Many of the hydrogen ions in both compartments will be buffered in a manner that allows there release
- The naive calculation is likely to be an underestimate because the pH in the inter-membrane space may be much lower.

If I were an ox-phos person I would know how many molecules of the ATP synthase complex there are per mitochondrion and the number of protons pumped into the membrane space per unit time. Such information would, presumably, bear on the problem.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question. Electrochemical gradient, as you mentioned it, relies on the CONCENTRATION gradient. The formula du=RTln(C1/C2)+zFdV, allows you to know if the transport is energetically favorable.and gives you a number for that energy change. The actual pumping however relies on the quantity, not on concentration. It is true that protons are pumped frome the inter-membrane space to the matrix, and that the concentration is higher there (about an order of magnitude).

Comment: My guess is that the volume of the intermembrane space will be smaller as well. But I will search the number to give you an actual quantity, to avoid subjective definitions, such as "small".

Comment: I´ve just find a paper that adresses this question, I leave it here in case anyone is interested:The Final Frontier of pH and the Undiscovered Country
Beyond
Wojciech Bal1
*, Ewa Kurowska1
, Wolfgang Maret2
1 Institute of Biochemistry and Biophysics, Polish Academy of Sciences, Warsaw, Poland, 2 King’s College London, Diabetes and Nutritional Sciences Division, London,
United Kingdom

Comment: @RosaliaMoretta — Your enthusiasm for a numerical approach to biology is admirable, but it is perhaps expressed in a manner other than expected on this list. As a poster your first obligation is to express your problem clearly. Your question still has an (unhelpful) title that appears at odds with your question, which is still not clearly explained. I will edit it slightly, but you need to correct the focus on the matrix alone, and present information on the pH of the intermembrane space. If the paper you mention is relevant you should summarize it and provide a journal reference.

Comment: @RosaliaMoretta I enjoyed your question, and this answer is excellent. Since you're new, let me point out what you should do [when someone answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Choose the best answer by clicking the little gray checkmark next to it (which turns it green). You should also upvote any useful answer when you have the upvote privilege. This answer should get both (an upvote and a checkmark).

Comment: I'm also surprised i was the only one to upvote the question... It's useful and quite clever

Comment: In view of the amendment to the question I have amended my answer, shortening the initial answer and adding to it in the light of the reference cited. I think @DeNovo for explaining the acceptance system, but suggest the poster should not be pressed to accept an answer she may not find satisfactory. I never taught or conducted research in the oxidative phosphorylation area, and am aware that there are people better placed to answer this question. But they are not on this list and it is August.